# Use SED to replace curlybrace and add insert a character

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a ".csv" file that is generated by a BASH script. Within that script I have a `sed` statement to make some changes in the file the script output just 1 line earlier. I'm trying to `sed` the file and remove/replace a few encoding characters.

I'm trying to replace '{' in the file, wherever it occurs, with a zero '0'. Additionally, I need to prepend the match with a plus '+'.

Here is the most recent try (of hundreds of previous tries): `sed -r 's/^(.*)([\{])(.*)$/\1\+0\3/g' -i "$FILENAME"`

Here is a sample of my data:

```
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,F,BI,,,D,7391420002
```

Frustratingly, it only seems to match the first line and then quit, despite the global flag '/g' being on:

```
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000+0,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,000000000000000{,000000000000011P,A,2006060000,,,F,BI,,,D,7391420002
```

Here is how I am trying to format it: (I included my next character replacement P=7):

```
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,F,BI,,,D,7391420002
```

My brain has been rendered to hamburger meat over this! :(

I sincerely appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**
This is conversion chart I'm working from:

```
Character   Digit   Sign
{   0   +
A   1   +
B   2   +
C   3   +
D   4   +
E   5   +
F   6   +
G   7   +
H   8   +
I   9   +

}   0   -
J   1   -
K   2   -
L   3   -
M   4   -
N   5   -
O   6   -
P   7   -
Q   8   -
R   9   -
```

Comment: Is there really four spaces at the start of each line?

Comment: No, that's just the stackoverflow formatting.  The beginning of the line has no leading characters, before the numbers start.

Comment: In this case remove them.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for your observations.

Comment: Has every field at most one char to replace? Or what sign(s)/output do you want for `,0{PP}{P},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate all the help! You all helped me get very close. In the end, this is what ended up solving the issues. THANK YOU!

```
        #!/bin/bash
    function FixEncodedStrings(){
    if [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})\{([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})\{([0-9]{1,})?/+\10\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})A([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})A([0-9]{1,})?/+\11\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})B([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})B([0-9]{1,})?/+\12\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})C([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})C([0-9]{1,})?/+\13\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})D([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})D([0-9]{1,})?/+\14\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})E([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})E([0-9]{1,})?/+\15\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})F([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})F([0-9]{1,})?/+\16\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})G([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})G([0-9]{1,})?/+\17\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})H([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})H([0-9]{1,})?/+\18\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})I([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})I([0-9]{1,})?/+\19\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})\}([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})\}([0-9]{1,})?/-\10\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})J([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})J([0-9]{1,})?/-\11\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})K([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})K([0-9]{1,})?/-\12\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})L([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})L([0-9]{1,})?/-\13\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})M([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})M([0-9]{1,})?/-\14\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})N([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})N([0-9]{1,})?/-\15\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})O([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})O([0-9]{1,})?/-\16\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})P([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})P([0-9]{1,})?/-\17\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})Q([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})Q([0-9]{1,})?/-\18\2/g'
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ([0-9]{3,})R([0-9]{1,})? ]]
        then
            echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})R([0-9]{1,})?/-\19\2/g'
    fi
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed`command was getting close. Two things to change:
Do not match beginning and end-of-line.
Match with characters that are not a `,`.
You will get

```
sed -r 's/,([^,]*)\{([^,])*/,+\10\2/g; s/,([^,]*)P([^,]*)/,-\17\2/g' "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. This matched EVERY column and appended EVERY result with either a '+' or '-' or '-+' ... here is what I tried:

Comment: s/,([^,]*)\{([^,])*/,+\10\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\A([^,])*/,+\11\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\B([^,])*/,+\12\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\C([^,])*/,+\13\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\D([^,])*/,+\14\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\E([^,])*/,+\15\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\F([^,])*/,+\16\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\G([^,])*/,+\17\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\H([^,])*/,+\18\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\I([^,])*/,+\19\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\}([^,]*)/,-\10\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\J([^,]*)/,-\11\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\K([^,]*)/,-\12\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\L([^,]*)/,-\13\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\M([^,]*)/,-\14\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\N([^,]*)/,-\15\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\O([^,]*)/,-\16\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\P([^,]*)/,-\17\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\Q([^,]*)/,-\18\2/g;s/,([^,]*)\R([^,]*)/,-\19\2/g'

Comment: i had to remove the `sed -r '` i ran out of characters here.

Comment: The second `*` in `s/,([^,]*)\A([^,])*/` is supposed to be inside the match.

Comment: sed -r '
s/,([^,]*)\{([^,]*)/,+\10\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\A([^,]*)/,+\11\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\B([^,]*)/,+\12\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\C([^,]*)/,+\13\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\D([^,]*)/,+\14\2/g
....
s/,([^,]*)\}([^,]*)/,-\10\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\J([^,]*)/,-\11\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\K([^,]*)/,-\12\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\L([^,]*)/,-\13\2/g
s/,([^,]*)\M([^,]*)/,-\14\2/g
' -i "$FILENAME"

Comment: same result, after I fixed the )* *) thing.

Comment: Did you have a `;` between the `g` and `s` ?

Comment: I figured it out -- User error (hahaha).  I had escaped the letters, creating (i think) character classes?  ... anyway -- unescaping the letters fixed it .... is there any way to make it apply only to digits?  All of my column headers are missing info, replaced .... instead of "And" I have "+1nd"

Comment: Try `s/,([0-9]*)A([0-9]*)/.../g`

Answer (score 1):

Good grief, just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    mkmap("{ A B C D E F G H I","+")
    mkmap("} J K L M N O P Q R","-")
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        for (char in map) {
            num = map[char]
            if ( sub(char,num,$i) ) {
                $i = pfx[char] $i
            }
        }
    }
    print
}
function mkmap(list,sign,       char,tmp,num) {
    split(list,tmp,/ /)
    for (num in tmp) {
        char = tmp[num]
        map[char] = num-1
        pfx[char] = sign
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+1,++29,,,+3,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+1,++29,,,+3,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+1,++29,,,+3,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+1,++29,,,+3,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+1,++29,,,+3,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+1,++29,,,+3,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+1,++29,,,+3,7639840002
4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+1,2006060000,,,+6,++29,,,+4,7391420002
```

You don't say what to do if 2 characters appear in a field so idk if what I'm doing above is what you want or not but that code should be trivial enough to modify to do whatever it is you want with that and to add whatever other transformations you need.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^,]*[{A-I]\+/+&/g;s/[^,]*[}J-R]\+/-&/g;y/{ABCDEFGHI}JKLMNOPQR/01234567890123456789/' file
```

First insert either `+` or `-` infront of fields containing the translation encodings. Then translate the encodings.

Answer (score 0):

after reading it again, here is another solution with `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
             {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                {if(gsub(/{/,0,$i)) $i="+"$i; 
                 if(gsub(/P/,7,$i)) $i="-"$i} }1' file

    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,A,BI,,,C,7639840002
    4240880002,9000413542,001,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,+0000000000000000,-0000000000000117,A,2006060000,,,F,BI,,,D,7391420002
```

Comment: Wow! That's beefy ... let me see if that works. I assume I can load in my other character transitions in the same "if(gsub)" syntax.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I think I've messed up your work.  When incorporated into the script, it just hangs on the awk statement (debug). @karakfa , can we chat?

Answer (score 0):

take +0 -0 +1 -1 out of your conversion chart, it should work.